# Cannot get ListItems with custom widgets to display

Tags: python, qt, pyside

I'm having issues getting items with custom widgets to show up in a list widget. The items show up blank in the example below...

```
from PySide2 import QtWidgets

class ItemWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
  def __init__(self,parent = None):
    super(ItemWidget, self).__init__(parent)
    layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
    self.setLayout(layout)
    self.checkBox = QtWidgets.QCheckBox()
    self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel('test')
    layout.addWidget(self.checkBox)
    layout.addWidget(self.label)

class ListWidget(QtWidgets.QListWidget):
    def __init__(self,parent = None):
        super(ListWidget,self).__init__(parent)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        for i in range(10):
            item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
            self.addItem(item)
            widget = ItemWidget(self)
            self.setItemWidget(item,widget)
            self.show()

lister = ListWidget()
```

Comment: `item.setSizeHint(widget.sizeHint())`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like QlistWidget won't do what you want, so you'll need to approach it from a lower level.

[**PySide.QtGui.QListWidget.setItemWidget(item, widget)**](http://pyside.github.io/docs/pyside/PySide/QtGui/QListWidget.html#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QListWidget.setItemWidget)

**This function should only be used to display static content in the place of a list widget item**. If you want to display custom dynamic content or implement a custom editor widget, use PySide.QtGui.QListView and subclass PySide.QtGui.QItemDelegate instead.